# Delete a record on a list - Android

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, local-storage

I have a list when click on the button of each record in the list I delete it.

I use this HTML5 on Anroaid by PhoneGap wrapper, on a computer the Record is deleted, on Android not! What could be the reason?

Here my code:

My list:

```
<ul id="MyList" data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
</ul>
```

I fill the list with this function:

```
function FillBookMarkListByStation() {
    var ul = $("#MyList");
    for (var i = 0; i < Local.length; i++) {
        var newLI = document.createElement("LI");
        ul.appendChild(newLI);
        newLI.innerHTML = '<a href="xxx.html" onclick="x();" > <p>...</p>' +
       '<a id="btnClear' + i + '" data-role="button" data-icon="delete" data-theme="b"></a> 
        </a>';
    $("#btnClear" + i).click(function () { Clear(ul, newLI); });

   }
  $('ul').listview('refresh');
}
```

Function clear:

```
function Clear(List, Delete) {
    //Remove from the list
    List.removeChild(Delete);
            //Remove from the local storage
            for (var i = 0; i < Local.length; i++) {
              //Checking is variable for check the data in the item
                if (Local[i].Checking == Delete.dataset.checking) {
                    if (Local.length == 1)
                        Local= [];
                    else {
                        for (var j = i; j < Local.length - 1; j++) {
                            Local[i] = Local[i] + 1;
                        }
                        Local.length--;
                    }
                    Local["loc"] = JSON.stringify(Local);    
                }
           }
     }
```

**On computer works fine,**

on Android is delete from the screen but not from loacl storage,

on presentation of the list is still showing the deleted item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, android will not know the dataset and therefore is stuck ..